# why is my d3 donut chart get torsion on updating?

Tags: d3.js

I am using `d3` to render a donut chart and it works fine for rendering the data on the first time. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

But when updating the data my component got torsion like below:

[image]

below code is for updating:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                            .sort(null)
                            .value(function(d) {
                                return d.val;
                            });

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                            .innerRadius(chart_r * 0.7)
                            .outerRadius(function() {
                                return (d3.select(this).classed('clicked'))? chart_r * 1.08
                                                                           : chart_r;
                            }).padAngle(0.05);

            // Start joining data with paths
            var paths = charts.selectAll('.donut')
                            .selectAll('path')
                            .data(function(d, i) {
                                return pie(d.data);
                            });

            paths
                .transition()
                .duration(10000)
                .attr('d', arc);

            paths.enter()
                .append('svg:path')
                    .attr('d', arc)
                    .style('fill', function(d, i) {
                        return color(i);
                    })
                    .style('stroke', '#FFFFFF')
                    .on(eventObj)

            paths.exit().remove();
```

the full code can be found: "https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/OQvJor". You can click on the refresh data button to see the issue.

How can I make it updating smoothly instead of torsion?

Comment: Could you provide a codepen with only 1 pie chart?

Comment: I have updated my codepen to show only one chart.

Comment: This should probably help: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410. The idea is to let d3 itself interpolate the different shapes pies will take during the transition. It uses an intermediate `_current` variable on each pie which represents the pie shapes before the transition and calling `d3.interpolate(this._current, a)` between this._current and a (the new shape) will make the trick.